# MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration application which reads a folder and sftp the files to multiple servers. I have referenced SI sample [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp).
When I run the application from my local windows machine, it does transfer successfully, but when I deploy it on UNIX machine it gives below error.

Can someone help here?

```
    org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to invoke handler; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy600.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:166)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at com.varun.FileSplitter.send(FileSplitter.java:125)
    at com.varun.FileSplitter.breakIt(FileSplitter.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:482)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
    Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:419)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:282)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:264)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$1.cloneAndExecute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:92)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice$2.doWithRetry(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:92)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:263)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:193)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:88)
    ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:382)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:408)
    ... 54 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:273)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:377)
    ... 56 more
    Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth cancel
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:511)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:264)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> failed to create SFTP Session

See [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-session-factory):

> If you experience connectivity problems and would like to trace Session creation as well as see which Sessions are polled you may enable it by setting the logger to TRACE level (e.g., log4j.category.org.springframework.integration.file=TRACE). Please also see Section 27.9, “SFTP/JSCH Logging”.

You definitely should observe anything else there in logs. Otherwise this generic StackTrace isn't useful.

Comment: Please, switch on debug logging for jscraft . It's still isn't obvious and really far from Spring Integration...